# Basic auth for Quart - python

Tags: python, basic-authentication, quart

I'm looking for using basic auth on Quart. I'm aware that quart-auth is available but it supports only cookies based authentication. Is there a way to use basic auth without resorting to use flask patch with Flask-BasicAuth ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how you can do it in Quart, (if you remove the `async` and `await` keywords and change `quart` to `flask` it will work for Flask as well).

```
from functools import wraps
from secrets import compare_digest

from quart import abort, current_app

def auth_required(func):

    @wraps(func)
    async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        auth = request.authorization
        if (
            auth is not None and 
            auth.type == "basic" and
            auth.username == current_app.config["BASIC_AUTH_USERNAME"] and
            compare_digest(auth.password, current_app.config["BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD"])
        ):
            return await func(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            abort(401)

    return wrapper

# Usage

@auth_required
@app.route("/")
async def index():
     return ""
```